# SRI check always failing for gtag js script in browser

Tags: gtag.js, subresource-integrity

I am trying to add subresource integrity hashes for the gtag script that my web application uses.
My issue is that no matter what hash I use for SRI, the browser always fails the SRI check for the gtag.

Is there a workaround for this so that I get the safety of SRI for gtag script?

I downloaded the gtag script using curl `curl https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js -o gtag.js`. I then calculate the sha384 hash using this `shasum -b -a 384 gtag.js | awk '{ print $1 }' | xxd -r -p | base64` command

I would expect the hash calculated using the command above to match with the script downloaded from the url.